# Get YouTube Video Description (YouTube API) for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, youtube-api

I'm working on an info app about a singer. Now I have to integrate her YouTube videos, playlists and comments on the videos, but I found no appropriate way to do it. This could be JSON returning a value, or just simple API that lets you receive info about a particular video on YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`videos/list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint of the YouTube v3 API with these parameters:

`part` -> `snippet`

`id` -> The video's video_id, example: `jCHE0Tjw6MA`

```
HTTP GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=jCHE0Tjw6MA&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Swift:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=jCHE0Tjw6MA&key={YOUR_API_KEY}")!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    do {
        if let parsedResponse: [String : AnyObject] = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? [String : AnyObject] {

            let description = parsedResponse["items"]![0]["description"] // the first item's decsription
            print(description) // "███████████████████▌HD / HQ Official Music Video ███████████████████▌\r\n\r\nReal Life - Send Me An Angel\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nreal life send me an angel official music video hq hd 1983 89 lyrics live cover remix extended original"
        }


    }
    catch {
        print("json error: \(error)")
    }

})
task.resume()
```